# background not visible due to positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

The background color of  list is not displayed properly. This problem started after I floated  left and  right. How to fix this.

Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ3nM/1/)

Similarly I've problem with the div .wrapper. The shadow should be way below the content and there should be a white color background beneath . [here is fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ3nM/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the CSS:

```
ol {overflow:hidden;}
```

and (2nd question):

```
.wrapper {overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: rocha -- thanks. can u pls let me know how to fix the <div class =wrapper> background?

Comment: @peterpan: Yes, it's the second part of my answer.